# Function starts being repeated over and over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I've been developing a simple system that is supposed to change between two different scenes when you press a button.

```
gameOne();

var game = 1;

function gameOne() {
  game = 1;
  console.log("Game 1");
  $( "body" ).keyup(function( event ) {
        if ( event.which == 49 && game == 1) { // Number 1 key
           gameTwo(); 
        }
  });
}

function gameTwo() {
  game = 2;
  console.log("Game 2");
  $( "body" ).keyup(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 49 && game == 2) { // Number 1 key
        gameOne();
    } 
  });
}
```

Expected behaviour - I want it to say Game 1, after after pressing the 1 key and then Game 2 after pressing the 1 key again, and then repeat this as I press 1.

Actual behaviour - It does the expected behaviour a few times, and then it starts repeating 1 and 2 over and over again, to the point it lags the browser out.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0npotm8/10/

I'm really sorry if this is a basic question or anything, I'm still fairly new to Javascript and JQuery and this is really confusing me currently.

All help is appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: Every time you call either method, you are creating a new keyup event handler on the body.  That's why you are seeing repetitive operations.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this? Thank you

Comment: Don't bind key events inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events. inside key events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are rebinding the `keyup` event recuresively inside the `keyup` callback, so it ends up by breaking the browser.

What you need to do is to get the `keyup` binding code out of the two functions:

```
gameOne();

var game = 1;

$("body").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 49 && game == 1) { // Number 1 key
    gameTwo();
  } else if (event.which == 49 && game == 2) { // Number 1 key
    gameOne();
  }
});


function gameOne() {
  game = 1;
  console.log("Game 1");
}

function gameTwo() {
  game = 2;
  console.log("Game 2");
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a delegate event handler to control actions like this, so you do not have to juggle event bindings around.

```js
var $container = $('#container').focus();

$(document.body)
  .on('keyup', '#container.game1', function(e){
    if (e.which == 49) {
      console.log('Game 1');
      $container.removeClass('game1').addClass('game2');
    }
  })
  .on('keyup', '#container.game2', function(e){
    if (e.which == 49) {
      console.log('Game 2');
      $container.removeClass('game2').addClass('game1');
    }
  });
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="game1" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

This logic creates two different delegate event handlers for the body.  Both filter out events for the `#container` child element of the body, but also filter based on an additional class on the container; game1 and game2.  Depending on which class the element has, only one of the event handlers will process.

Answer (score -1):

what about something like:

```js
let game = 1;
document.onkeyup = ev => {
  if (ev.which === 49) {
    console.log(`Game ${game}`);
    game = game === 1 ? 2 : 1;
  }
};
```

will it solve your issue?

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you call `keyup` on an element, you attach another event handler. To catch events, you only need to call it once. The callback functions that handle the event will fire every time the event happens.